# how to store data in memory?

Tags: python, django

I have a form to search for a pattern. It has two fields- one for pattern and other for type info. I have a function in view which searches pattern and returns result which should be displayed in same form. And i'm instantiating a string when pattern is searched. I want to persist that for next pattern searches.

```
forms.py

class fillconfigForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(fillconfigForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        CHOICES=[('1','Command'),('2','Output')]
        self.fields['Type'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer),required=True)
        self.fields['Pattern'] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea,required=True)

views.py

def get_ticket_pattern(request):
      form = forms.fillconfigForm(request.POST or None)
      if request.POST:
           ptype = request.POST['Type']
           pattern = request.POST['Pattern']
           print 'gone---------',proc_id,ptype
           list_found = mysite.build_config.pattern_find_call(pattern,ptype)
           return list_found
```

i need to return this list and display it after each search. is there any way to store this much data in memory so as to search for every request sent

Comment: You should look at using the caching framework in Django, as that is what it does.

Comment: Why would you want to use mongo db? You could probably hack it together, but I wouldn't recommend it, there are multiple cache backends, memory or database or file, I am sure one of those is far better suited to your needs. 

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/